# How can i deselct all option but i should be able to select after submit (notify) using ajax in choosen js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

[ui][1]

This is my UI and after notification is passed i automatically want to deselect all and open for selection again
This is my Javscript code using jquery ajax . After notification is passed i want to update chosen select
[myjs][2]

```
function InsertNotify() {
alertify.confirm('Notify', 'Are you sure you want to send notification', function () { FNotify(); }
    , function () { alertify.error('Cancel') });
function FNotify() {
    var notifyObj = {
        supporterid: $(".supporters").val(),
        HospitalUpdateId: $("#hiddenid").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Notify/InsertNotify",
        type: "POST",
        data: notifyObj,

        success: function (result) {
            toastr.success("The notification passed successfully");
            $("#dropdown").val('');
            $("#dropdown").trigger("chosen:updated");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            toastr.error("Error in sending notifications");
        }
    });
}
```

}

$("#dropdown").val('') didn't work

This is my code at frontend

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedArray, new MultiSelectList(Model.supporters, "Id", "Name"), new { id = "dropdown", multiple = "multiple" })
            <input type="hidden" id="notifytabtype" name="Type" />
            <input type="hidden" id="notifytabid" name="Id" />
            <input type="hidden" id="notifyhospitalid" name="HospitalId" />
            <button class="btn btn-danger" value="Notify" style="width:60px;height:30px;" id="notifysubmit" onclick="submitter()">Notify</button>
```

$("#dropdown").chosen();
js to show

Comment: Post your code as text not images .

Comment: Ok I have edited , have a look

Comment: Instead of `$("#dropdown").val('')` try `$("#dropdown option").prop("selected", false);`